# Mysql Query vs XML Data in php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

We are building a website which would serve about 30k unique visitors a day.
Currently we use a simple mysql Connect > A Simple Query > mysql Close.

I'm afraid that with a dual core server running 2GB of RAM we would be able
to open about 1k mysql connection tops. is 1k a good estimate?

Is it better to make a Cron-Job output XML files and let our php files grab the data from them?

Comment: i would consider db+file cache

Comment: Can you elaborate on the file cache, i'm coming from a programming environment and have little clue about how to set up such a thing

Comment: one suggestion below, there's a few other about, just google php cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically XML will never be faster than MySQL for searching data (i.e. performing queries).

I don't know what kind of data you have, but XML will only be faster if you have a bunch of simple files and don't need to search, just load the files and format them.

If you need to search, then use MySQL.
MySQL does all sorts of optimizations. For example it stores KEY columns in a separate file, allowing for a *much* faster search.

Comment: no need for search. the XML file would be exactly what i need, simple xml loading & listing results using a For Each loop

Comment: Then using XML files **may** be faster. No guarantees though, remember MySQL also does caching -- You can write a script/daemon to cache stuff, but then you might be better off with MySQL And MEMORY tables .... As a sidenote, if you only have "flat" data and no need for XML's nesting features, you'll be better of with CSV IMHO. PHP provides `fgetcsv()` and `fputscsv()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Zend cache](http://phpdev.ro/how-to-store-zend-cache-results-into-mysql.html) for caching MySQL query results for the the data that doesn't change frequently.